# Create a new data frame by subsetting all the data frames in a dictionary using a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of data frames:

```
two_season_bucket_suffixes = {'two_season_bucket_year1_racer_bio':two_season_bucket_year1_racer_bio,
'two_season_bucket_year1_spring_rate':two_season_bucket_year1_spring_rate,
'two_season_bucket_year1_neaps_rate':two_season_bucket_year1_neaps_rate,
'two_season_bucket_year1_spring_raw':two_season_bucket_year1_spring_raw,
'two_season_bucket_year1_neap_raw':two_season_bucket_year1_neap_raw,
'two_season_bucket_year1_opposing_team':two_season_bucket_year1_opposing_team,
'two_season_bucket_year1_opposing_team_distribution':two_season_bucket_year1_opposing_team_distribution,
'two_season_bucket_year1_stern_score':two_season_bucket_year1_stern_score,
'two_season_bucket_year1_bow_score':two_season_bucket_year1_bow_score,
'two_season_bucket_year1_team_score':two_season_bucket_year1_team_score,
'two_season_bucket_year2_racer_bio':two_season_bucket_year2_racer_bio,
'two_season_bucket_year2_spring_rate':two_season_bucket_year2_spring_rate,
'two_season_bucket_year2_neaps_rate':two_season_bucket_year2_neaps_rate,
'two_season_bucket_year2_spring_raw':two_season_bucket_year2_spring_raw,
'two_season_bucket_year2_neap_raw':two_season_bucket_year2_neap_raw,
'two_season_bucket_year2_opposing_team':two_season_bucket_year2_opposing_team,
'two_season_bucket_year2_opposing_team_distribution':two_season_bucket_year2_opposing_team_distribution,
'two_season_bucket_year2_stern_score':two_season_bucket_year2_stern_score,
'two_season_bucket_year2_bow_score':two_season_bucket_year2_bow_score,
'two_season_bucket_year2_team_score':two_season_bucket_year2_team_score}
```

they all have different columns, but they all have at least one column that starts with the word 'prediction'

I would like to create a new dataframe out of every column that starts with 'prediction':

```
two_season_bucket_prediction= pd.DataFrame()
counter = 0
for key, val in two_season_bucket_suffixes.items():
    if counter == 0:
        two_season_bucket_prediction= val[val.columns[pd.Series(val.columns).str.startswith('prediction')]]
    else:
        two_season_bucket_prediction= two_season_bucket_prediction.join(val[val.columns[pd.Series(val.columns).str.startswith('prediction')]])
        counter += 1
```

every time I just end up with a data frame with one column named 'prediction', even though I am sure no column is only named prediction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are increasing the counter where you dont reach ever:

```
two_season_bucket_prediction= pd.DataFrame()
counter = 0
for key, val in two_season_bucket_suffixes.items():
    if counter == 0:
        two_season_bucket_prediction= val[val.columns[pd.Series(val.columns).str.startswith('prediction')]]
    else:
        two_season_bucket_prediction= two_season_bucket_prediction.join(val[val.columns[pd.Series(val.columns).str.startswith('prediction')]])
    counter += 1
```

Comment: ok so I moved the counter to the same indent as the if, but I still end up with just one column in the new data frame

Comment: Your initial data is not enough so that I can help. Please update your question to. a runnable sample so that I can help you.